# HTTP Request getting sent multiple times

Tags: angular, http, xmlhttprequest, angular-httpclient

I am using angular 6
What I am trying to achieve is, on a "Submit" button click, I will hit an API with a JSON object(the api takes around 30 seconds to give response), and I want to show the response obtained in a text area.

The problem I am having is, on clicking the button, I receive the response with 200 OK status, but after that 2 more requests are going, which give 502 proxy error, I am unable to understand why those 2 additional requests are going.

(The request goes through an apache httpd server request mapping (reverse proxy))

dummy.component.ts

```
public validate(logObject) {
    this.service.validateConfig(logObject).pipe(
        takeUntil(this.ngXUnsubscribe)).
        subscribe(data => {
            this._logger.warn(JSON.stringify(data));
            this.sampleResult = JSON.stringify(data); // show result obtained in a text area
        },
            error => {
                this._logger.warn("#Inside ERROR FUNCTION");
                this._logger.warn(error);
            },
            () => {
                this._logger.warn("NO ERRORS");
            });
}
```

dummy.service.ts

```
public validateConfig(logObject) {
    return this.http.post(this.url + "/dummy/validate", logObject);
}
```

Requests:

[image]

First request:

[image]

Comment: It should work as expected. We are calling subscribe only once which will trigger API also only once. May be you can try event.stopPropagation() or define a flag and set to true initially. Using setTimeout, reset to false after 2 to 3 sec. Execute the Http Call only if flag is false.

Comment: What is ngxUnsubscribe ? remove it once and see the result